# ImageButtons overlap in GridLayout, but don't want this

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having problems with a GridLayout. In the layout below, phone_image and voip_image overlap and I don't want them to. phone_image is in column 0 and voip_image is in column 2.

SSCCE on Github
https://github.com/emnrd-ito/LayoutDemo

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/container_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <GridLayout xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/individual_gridlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:rowCount="7">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/division_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="3"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/employee_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Nobody Lastname"
            tools:text="name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/division"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="My Division"
            tools:text="division" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:text="My Title"
            tools:text="position" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:text="123 Sesame St."
            tools:text="address" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city_state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:text="mycity, mystate"
            tools:text="city,state" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:text="(555) 555-5555"
            tools:text="phone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:text="someone@somewhere.com"
            tools:text="email" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/directions_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_enabled" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/phone_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_enabled" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/voip_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_voip_enabled" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/email_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_email_enabled" />

    </GridLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Edit:
I tried using `Space` like so:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.Space
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:layout_column="1"
 android:layout_row="5"/>
```

It seems to insert about 1/2 column, whereas using the blank image inserts a whole column. There may be parameters to play within the Space component though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to create a blank image and put it in the drawable folder.
Then use it to take up space in the layout like so:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/phone_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_enabled" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/blank_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_blank" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/voip_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_voip_enabled" />
```

Comment: As a side comment, you can use also a `Space` view: `android.support.v4.widget.Space` instead of another ImageButton. Indeed, it was invented exactly with this purpose: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html

Comment: I didn't know about `Space`, thanks for pointing it out. I tried it real quick and it does indeed separate the 2 icons. It seems to insert about 1/2 column, whereas using the blank image inserts a whole column. There may be parameters to play with in the `Space` component though. So additional info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give `android:maxWidth` property to both `voipImage` and `phoneImage` `ImageButton`s, like this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/phone_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:maxWidth="96dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_enabled" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/voip_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:maxWidth="96dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_voip_enabled" />
```

**Update**

The above changes are not necessary. I think that to solve your problem you can simply change the `layout_column` property of `voip_image` like this:

```
android:layout_column="1"
```

Hope this can help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Neither of your suggestions work. Setting the  `maxwidth` has no effect and even if it did, in a more realistic example, the image size would vary with screen density. Setting `layout_column` to 1 does indeed
separate the 2 icons but then causes the voip_image and the text to its right to overlap.

Comment: I think setting maxWidth (and also maxHeight) property has the advantage (in a realistic example) to limit the expansion of the image, which can cause problems to the entire layout. But however you're right, things that I have proposed do not solve the general problem